# numpy memmap read error memory mapped size must be positive

Tags: python, numpy, binaryfiles, integer-overflow, numpy-memmap

I am reading a large binary file in partitions. 
Each partition is mapped using `numpy.memmap`.

The file consist of 1M rows, where a row is 198 2-byte integers. 
A partition is 1000 rows long.

Below is the code snippet:

```
mdata = np.memmap(fn, dtype='int16',  mode='r', offset=offset *2)
data = np.array(mdata[0:count])
```

here offset is 1000 * 198 * 2 * `partition_idx` where `partition_idx` ranges from `[0:1000]`. Count is 1000.

I get the error: memory mapped size must be positive

Comment: You're mapping the entire file into memory, not just the partition you're trying to work with.  Try adding ``shape=(198000,)`` or ``shape=(1000,198)`` to the memmap call to specify the size.